# Why am I close to being banned from serverfault?

Tags: support

I saw the below message just now when about to ask a question on the site:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

The problem is, from what I can tell on my profile for this site, I have exactly two questions that I asked about 3 years ago, both of which have positive (yet low) votes. One was left without marking an answer as accepted, so I took the liberty of doing that right now.

So what justification might there be for blocking my account based on two fairly benign questions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You also have two deleted questions, one deleted by yourself and one closed and then autodeleted. Both got downvotes, and these count for the mechanic that triggers that warning.

[You can't see your own deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) in your profile, but I can link them here if you want (which makes them also visible to some high-level users).