# Can someone let me see my deleted questions?

Tags: support

I got the same message as the person who posted this question:

[Why am I close to being banned from serverfault?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8192/why-am-i-close-to-being-banned-from-serverfault)

My profile says I haven't ever asked a question on serverfault, but maybe I did and it was deleted. In the answer to that question, Sven said "I can link them here if you want" -- could that be done for me?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for that, but there's nothing about those messages (other than the fact that no one answered) that I think is wrong, and no comments or any other indication that someone thought they were bad questions. What can I do now?

Comment: If you think your question can be deleted, always save its url. On this URL, you will be always capable to see that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- https://serverfault.com/questions/551277/subinacl-exe-does-not-seem-to-work-for-trustedinstaller-what-is-the-sid-to
- https://serverfault.com/questions/432283/sharing-not-boot-ssd-on-win7-64-bit-machine-is-not-effective

One was migrated to SU and deleted afterwards. The other was [autodeleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion/177675#177675) after one year with few views and no upvotes or answers. [From my understanding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91957/148043), this shouldn't contribute to a possible question ban, but the exact details of the algorithm are kept secret.

You don't  need to do anything except making sure that if you ask a question, it will be a good, on-topic question. Read the help center and [How to ask better questions on Serverfault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608) to help you with that. Also, make sure to read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997) if you happen to trigger the ban anyway.